# Central limit theorem independent distributions

Tags: statistics

I'm confused by the statement of the central limit theorem we've been given:

'If you take the sum $X$ of $N$ independent variables $x_i$, each taken from a distribution with mean $\mu_i$, then the distribution for $X$ has the average $\Sigma\mu_i$.'

So does this mean that if I take one number $x_i$ from a distribution and repeat the process $N$ times, then sum them I'll get a distribution that has mean $\Sigma\mu_i$? Where $\mu_i$ are the means of the distributions each $x_i$ has come from?

Or is it saying that if I take a sample $x_i$ each containing multiple numbers and calculate the mean of each sample to be $\mu_i$, then the distribution formed by the sample means has mean $\Sigma\mu_i$? Or something completely different?

I think what particularly confuses me is the idea that the mean of the new distribution $X$ should be a sum of means, because then won't your mean get bigger the more distributions you gather the $x_i$ from? But if all the distributions have a mean of 0.5 say, why should the distribution $X$ have a mean of $0.5N$? Our lecturer did show us that
$$<X>=<\Sigma x_i>=\Sigma<x_i>=\Sigma\mu_i$$
But I can't get my head around the result.

Comment: The  sum of  random variables $X_i$ has the mean $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mu_i$. For instance: $Y=X_1+X_2$. Then $E(Y)=E(X_1)+E(X_2)=\mu_1+\mu_2$. It is not necessary that the random variables are independent due to the linearity of expectation.

Comment: @callculus That confuses me. If both $X_1$ and  $X_2$ come from distributions with means of $0.5$ then you'd expect both to have a value of 0.5 (not exactly, but just on average if the sample size is big enough) and I'd expect the mean of the sum to be (0.5+0.5)/2=0.5. Is that just completely wrong? And based on flawed reasoning?

Comment: You take the average and the you´re wondering why it is not the sum? You can also calculate the expected value of the mean of two random variables It is $\mathbb E\left( \frac{X_1+X_2}{2} \right)=\mathbb E\left( \frac{X_1}{2} \right)+\mathbb E\left( \frac{X_2}{2} \right)$. If they are identical distributed then we get $\mathbb  E\left( \frac{X_1+X_1}{2}\right)=\mathbb  E\left( \frac{2X_1}{2}\right)=\mathbb E(X_1)=\mu_1=\mu_2$